# For each line in file execute command synchronously and save to newline of another file

Tags: linux, bash, perl, text, line-by-line

I have a `wget` script named `Chktitle.sh` -- this script takes a command like below

```
$ Chktitle.sh "my url"
```

I then have a file name `url.txt` with over 100 lines with urls and ips to check for web-page titles.
Then i have `results.txt` as a blank file.

Is there any way I can perform a repetitive action like below for each line in the file:

```
 Grab line1 from url.txt
 -----
 then execute Chktitle.sh "line1"
 -----
 Now save the result for line1 in results.txt
 -----
 Now goto Line2 ........


 etc etc etc
```

I need to make sure that it will only execute the next line after the previous one has finished.
Can any one show me any easy way to perform this? I am happy to use Perl, sh, and consider other languages..

The contents of `chktitle.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
string=$1"/search/"
wget --quiet -O - $string \
| sed -n -e 's!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p'
```

Comment: I would say that it was much better to put the whole thing into a single Perl script. (Perl because I'm better at it than shell.) What's inside `Chktitle.sh`? Is it complex?

Comment: no it is not complex just like this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this could help (provided that I understood correctly) :

```
while read line; do
    /path/to/Chktitle.sh x"$line" >> results.txt;
done < /path/to/input.txt
```

For each line in `/path/to/input.txt`, execute your script and append the output (`>>`) to `results.txt`.

Of course you could always add additional statements in your while loop :

```
while read line; do
    # Initialise var to output of chktitle
    var=$(/path/to/Chktitle.sh x"$line");

    # Add conditions
    if [ "$var" = "google" ]; then
        echo "google" >> result.txt;
    else
        echo "not google" >> result.txt;
    fi
done < /path/to/input.txt
```

Comment: this looks like what i need i forgot to ask also can you do and if else stament in your example if chktitle result = google save to results else do nothing and move to the next url

Comment: @LeoBishop : Edited. Hope that helps. Tbh, would also add a test to verify that the result file exists. 

A good starting point could be this (sorry for the lack of line breaks) :
`base="/tmp";
result="result.txt";

if [ ! -d "$base" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$base"; touch "$base/$result";
fi` or the directory could exist but the file not, or they could both exist and you want to crush the result.txt at each run, and so forth..

Comment: It would be more efficient to do the redirection outside the loop. So `while do; ...; done <input >output`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do this in Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $inputFile = 'url.txt';
open (my $fh, '<', $inputFile) or die "Could not open file '$inputFile': $!\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    my $url=chomp;
    my $str=get($url);
    if (! defined $str) {
        warn "Could not find page '$url'\n";
        next;
    }
    my ($title)=$str=~ m{<title>(.*?)</title>}s;
    if (! defined $title) {
        warn "No title in document '$url'\n";
        next;
    }
    print "$title\n";
}
close ($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat url.txt | xargs -I{} ./Chktitle.sh {} >> results.txt
```

See [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), especially the `-I` switch.

This `xargs` call will read the input (`url.txt`) line by line and call `./Chktitle.sh` with each such read line as a parameter.

The `{}` is the placeholder for the line read. You can also write

```
cat url.txt | xargs -Ifoo ./Chktitle.sh foo >> results.txt
```

(with `foo` as placeholder) but `{}` is the placeholder that is usually used for `xargs`.

Answer (score -2):

You can create your script with 2 parameters as follows

**HOW SCRIPT WORKS ON COMMAND LINE**

```
< script >  < path to url file >    <path to excuting script>
```

.
**The codes are broken down as follows with explanation**

**STEP 1**

```
#!/bin/bash
 rm -f "/root/Desktop/result.txt 2> /dev/null
```

remove any file that has the name result.txt so that i can create a new blank file

**STEP 2**

```
while read -r my_url; do 
"$2" "$my_url" >> "/root/Desktop/result.txt" 
done < "$1"
```

Set up a while do loop to read all lines in the url file (which is known as"$1").

Each line read is saved as "my_url".

The loop take your script script (Chktitle.sh - $2) followed by the line read known as "my_url" and execute it on the command line and redirect the output to result.txt. This is done for each line.

**NOW LET US SUMMARIZE ALL THE CODES INTO ONE SCRIPT AS FOLLOWS**

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f result.txt 2> /dev/null
while read -r my_url; do
"$2" "$my_url" >> "/root/Desktop/result.txt"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Why would you write the `root` hierarchy, and why would `root` have a `Desktop` in the first place? Unnerving.