# simple wget title grabber how can i split results that i need to a file

Tags: string, bash, text, append, wget

i have this bash script that uses wget to grab a web-page title 
this works perfect if i run it as is i give it a url and it shows me the result in the terminal

problem is i want to be able to save it to a file but only if the result is a exact match to a specified word like INEEDTHISSTRING

so if it matches the string above add the url used to result.txt (already contains urls) and move on to the next line

if not then do not do anything and move onto the next line

here is my chktitle.sh file contents can any body help me

```
#!/bin/bash
string=$1"/search/"
wget --quiet -O - $string \
| sed -n -e 's!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p'
```

Comment: sample input and required output would remove the ambiguity from your question ;-). Otherwise we get to spend our time guessing what you consider good output. Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For each line in file execute command syncronously and save to newline of another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302631/for-each-line-in-file-execute-command-syncronously-and-save-to-newline-of-anothe)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="$1/search/"
wget --quiet -O - "$url" |
    grep -q '<title>INEEDTHISSTRING</title>' &&
    echo "$url" >> result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in $1; do
var=`wget --quiet -O -  "$i"|sed -n -e 's!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p'| grep -o '\<INEEDTHISSTRING\>'`
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
echo "$i" >> result.txt
else
continue
fi
done
```

Note: My interpretation of the question

You have several urls separated by a space as one big arugment enclosed by single quotes as follows:

```
chktitle.sh 'www.google.com www.yahoo.com wwww.hotmail.com'
```

For each url the codes will wget that url title.If there are any words in the title matches your string 'INEEDTHISSTRING',it will store the url and move on to the next url. If no match found for a url it will skip that url and move on.

**Please advise me if I didn't get the full grasp of your question** 
Also ensure you delete any result.txt file before running the codes since it will append the results to your existing result.txt